# Retrieving ETags with a batchrequest

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've run into a small problem regarding ETags with the Facebook API. I'm trying to get a batch of albums from a page accompanied by their ETags. The problem is that the only way that i can manage to get said tags are with individual node requests for each album. Batch requests do not produce any ETags for the albums and neither do individual edge requests.

I'm not sure if it's true or not (because i can't find enough documentation about Facebook Etag support)but it seems to me that ETags are only really produced for each each individual HTTP request.

Comment: Are you talking about actual batch requests, as Facebook defines the term? Because those should return the headers and body for the individual requests. Show code please. And also, what do you need those ETags for?

Comment: Yes that's exacly what i'm talking about.But i've figured it out. I will be doing a response to my own post some day explaining what and how the problem is. 

Simply put. The problem is how the response header is packaged for each request in a batch request compared to a singel request.